# Displaying custom objects in communities

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, partner-communities

Just need info about displaying the custom object in Salesforce Communities. 
Have added the custom profile in the Communities. 
I have created a custom profile by cloning the Customer Community profile, have given the Read/Write permission on the custom object, but when we are trying to access the community through the Community user credentials, that custom object is not visible. 
Ironically, the standard objects are visible through the Community Users with that custom profile. 
Is it the license issue or using the right profile issue??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88752/discussion-on-question-by-vineet-displaying-custom-objects-in-communities).

Comment: Actually got the answer.  The deployment status should be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deployment status field on the custom object was set to In Development.  I changed it to Deployed.